# Java stream type issue

Tags: java, java-stream

Somehow I can't use check on `instanceof` in stream. The problem occurred in test:

```
ArgumentCaptor<MyClass> arg = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(MyClass.class);
verify(modelService).save(arg.capture());
```

Method `save` called three times with different arguments(instances of different classes), and `arg.getAllValues()` returned `SomeOtherClassObject1,SomeOtherClassObject2,MyClassObject`

Stream bellow throws exception "SomeOtherClass can not be cast to MyClass"

```
MyClass argument = arg.getAllValues().stream()
.filter(v -> v instanceof MyClass)
.findFirst()
.get()
```

But if I use foreach everything works fine:

```
MyClass argument = null;
for(Object o : arg.getAllValues()) {
    if(o instanceof MyClass) {
        argument = (MyClass) o;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `filter` doesn't change the type of your stream. For that, use `map` with a cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for each loop example shown in the question contains an explicit cast after the instanceof check. The following would be equivalent to that loop:

```
MyClass argument =
    arg.getAllValues()
        .stream()                            // Stream<SomeOtherClass>
        .filter(v -> v instanceof MyClass)   // Stream<SomeOtherClass>
        .map(MyClass.class::cast)            // Stream<MyClass>
        .findFirst()                         // Optional<MyClass>
        .orElse(null);                       // MyClass
```

Comment: Just a little addition: You may also write `MyClass.class::isInstance` instead of `v -> v instanceof MyClass` for reasons of consistency.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this **casting**. Because `filter` only filtering the stream according to your checking rule. This is one solution to resolve problem. Or use `map` to cast.

```
MyClass argument = ((MyClass)arg.getAllValues()
    .stream().
    .filter(v -> v instanceof MyClass)
    .findFirst()
    .get());
```

PS: `map` is more relevant to if your results more than one to apply for all. In your problem **casting** is more appropriate

Comment: You don’t need to put brackets around the entire expression. By the way, `map` is also useful when you chain additional stages which depend on the type.